# Do we really need a tag synonym to cover a typo?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Looking at the [tag-info synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms) for [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), there is a synonym for [sql-srever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-srever).

<kbd>[image: Screenshot of tag wiki, showing question synonyms with sql-srever highlighted]</kbd>

Seeing as it's a typo, what value does it have other than auto-redirecting a few folks who might mistype it?

I've not seen other tags with typo synonyms.

Can/should this be removed?

Comment: Well, it does mention "alternate spellings" - who knows, maybe that's an accepted spelling alternative in the MSSQL community?

Comment: @l4mpi it's not an accepted spelling alternative, it's simply a typo.

Comment: I guess I should have added `<sarcasm></sarcasm>` tags to my previous comment...

Comment: @l4mpi sarcasm is the lowest form of wit... but it's still my favorite!

Comment: this tag makes me feel we better preemptively add tag [tag:sql-sever]

Comment: Misspelled tags should be removed... less clutter is always good....

Comment: people commonly misspell [tag:java] as [tag:javascript] on a regular basis, and ignore the warning in the tag; should we synonymize that as well?

Comment: How come [server](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/server/synonyms) has no synonyms?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since its creation in December 2013, there have been 15 uses of the misspelled tag, the last of which was a couple of weeks ago.

I wouldn't call it a *common* misspelling (< 1 use per month), but if people are actively misspelling it then I see no harm in leaving it in there for the system to correct automatically.

Comment: I guess there's no harm, I'm just being particular because I'm active in that tag and don't like clutter :-)

Comment: @Tanner: Good thing we don't have synonyms for every single possible way to misspell a word (yet).

Comment: Careful... you might open the floodgates!!!!

Comment: I'm not sure this number means anything. I believe "uses" of a synonym includes when it is selected from the auto-complete tag list. If the misspelling wasn't in the auto-complete list in the first place I have an idea it would have even less "uses".

Comment: That particular one seems more like an accident of history than anything else. [Even I](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html) didn't have it (added today).

Answer (score 10):

**Synonym tags don't display like normal tags when asking questions**, but if someone makes the typo, the tag we want them to select shows. If you press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will autocorrect it. If you press <kbd>Space</kbd>, it will appear to take the misspelling. However, when the question is posted, it will autocorrect to the actual tag.

[image: Choose a tag]

Therefore, we want to keep it. It's likely that someone saw a pattern at some point of people misspelling it, and consequently creating another tag in our already extensive tag library, so they created a synonym to automatically move those to the correct tag so the questions didn't stay out of view of those following the tag.

We're not going to go start creating synonyms of every common misspelling of every tag we can think of, but if we see a pattern of a misspelled tag start to gain traction, we might:

- Retag all questions with the correct tag and keep an eye to make sure the misspelling doesn't reappear.
- Create a synonym for tag misspellings that just won't go away.

Comment: Looking at BoltClock's answer: _"Since its creation in December 2013, there have been 15 uses of the misspelled tag"_ I wouldn't call that a pattern that warrants it's own tag. It is good however that the search corrects it... I'd still like to see it burn though!

Comment: One thing on the search though, if you simply type it and press space instead of clicking the suggested tag, you still get the incorrect tag rather than an auto-correction.

Comment: @Tanner You are correct, if you press space, it appears to allow it. However, when the question is posted, it will automatically switch to the correct tag. By creating the synonym, we assure that that misspelling can never be created as an actual tag. It doesn't appear in tag listing, so it's really not doing harm.

Answer (score 6):

Given that there are now prompts on SO that warn you before creating a tag, I find keeping synonyms to be counter productive. Is quite hard to mess up writing "sql-s" and not selecting [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), and even if you do, the system will inform you. I found that users use tag synonyms to be less about actual "synonyms" (alternative common spellings for the exact same thing) and more a tool of "I can't be bothered to do it right".

Answer (score -6):

I agree, the small usefulness of this is not worth the big problem: practically every tag has hundreds (or even thousands) of typos.  We can't possibly correct them all or even a good portion of them or else every tag would have so many synonyms that it would undercut the real purpose of synonyms: not typos, but very similar things (such as [ios-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-widget) and [widgetkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widgetkit)).  As for typos, let editors handle that, and besides, a question with a typo tag usually means the OP hasn't put much effort into the question and it should be closed/deleted.