# Burninate [management-studio]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management-studio), as it stands right now, has 52 questions tagged. Every question is dealing with [sql-management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-management-studio).

The [management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management-studio) tag doesn't actually have a wiki of its own, and it looks to be just a mis-tag for [sql-management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-management-studio).

Since there really isn't any point of having the [management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management-studio) tag if it's just a mistag, is it possible to blacklist the tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for those to be out there, how about we just make both [sql-management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-management-studio) and [management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management-studio) a synonym of [ssms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms)?  They were both already pending synonyms on [ssms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms) just waiting more approvals.

I've just made them synonyms and merged them. It should clear things up a bit.

Comment: but we still have [typos](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289653/do-we-really-need-a-tag-synonym-to-cover-a-typo) :)

Comment: @Tanner possibly, but I don't see any harm in catching that typo as a synonym.

Comment: What's people's feeling on SSMS being the primary? I feel that of the three, the acronym is arguably the least informative to the reader as to what it refers to.

Comment: @sphanley I'd suggest making that a different discussion topic.  The others had already been suggested as synonyms of `ssms` (and had upvotes to approve it) so I just cemented it.