# Why can you suggest an edit that just changes a tag to one of its synonyms?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, tag-synonym-process

While working through the suggested edit review queue, I noticed an editor who's been submitting a mass quantity of tag-only edits, removing tags that say "don't use me" from very, very old questions. I left a comment for the editor and flagged one of the posts in question to let the mods know in case they want to intervene (so let's not make this about the user), but while I was doing so something jumped out at me: in some cases, there were edits such as [revision four on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/332574/revisions) where the suggested edit simply removed one tag and replaced it with another that's already a tag synonym for the original!

It seems like there's very, very few scenarios where changing a tag to another synonym for the same tag while changing nothing else in the post would represent a high-quality edit. In this case, at least to my eye, [ssms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms) seems like a LESS readable, informative tag than [management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management-studio). Is this supposed to be possible? Should this sort of edit be prevented by the system, or are there appropriate cases where synonym retags make sense and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: I think this falls under the "robots are too dumb to make good decisions" umbrella.  That's why you as a human are charged with making these decisions to accept/reject such edits.

Comment: @sphanley, I think I should clarify. My original edits were originally supposed to be changing management-studio to sql-management-studio (which, I believe, is more readable). To tell you the truth, I didn't know they synonym smss existed until I put in the burninate/retag request. I didn't really know how to go about getting things re-tagged, so I just started editing posts. That's when I noticed a post someone left on one of my questions about burninating, so I stopped and put in the request.

Comment: @DylanCorriveau, that's about what was explained by animuson below, and this particular edit makes a lot more sense now. As an aside, something I wanted to let you know generally, though is that your other edits that seem to be trying to burninate tags such as apple or microsoft aren't necessarily ideal - even though those tags say not to use them, flooding the edit queue with very, very old (especially so if they're already closed) posts that aren't harming anyone doesn't add a lot of value to the site and is often discouraged.

Comment: @sphanley sure, but isn't that how you burninate a tag? Isn't the point of burninating to remove all instances of the tag?

Comment: @DylanCorriveau Yes, but not every bad tag gets chosen to be burninated, and especially not through **suggested** edits. There's no reason to use reviewer time to sign off on removing tags from closed questions from 2009 - if that's going to be done at all, it's better done by people whose edits don't go to the queue.

Comment: @DylanCorriveau for more guidance on this point and others related to tag burnination, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate. Important points from the bottom section: a) don't do it if your edits are suggested, and b) even if they aren't, don't do it alone manually if there's more than a few dozen questions with the tag. Both of those guidelines apply here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, first off, they *didn't*. At the time they proposed the edit, the tags weren't synonyms. In fact, if you look at the [actual suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8038280), they proposed changing the tag from [management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management-studio) to [sql-management-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-management-studio). When the edit was finally approved, the [synonym now existed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294103/burninate-management-studio) and their proposed tag got rewritten to the new master tag when the edit was applied.

But all of that aside, why *shouldn't* users be able to retag things to the master tag? To be perfectly clear, they can *only* suggest a retag to the master tag. You can't edit a post and change a tag back to one of the synonyms - only a rollback like you've done can do that.

We prefer that no synonyms have questions tagged under them, and that *all* the questions be retagged to whatever the master tag is for that group of synonyms. Most of the time, a moderator will perform a merge to make this happen. But for some smaller tags, it's not worthwhile to get a moderator involved and letting users edit (or suggest edits) to replace all the tags with the new master tag is perfectly appropriate.

If you think the [ssms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms) is inappropriate or unreadable, then you can discuss that and maybe get it changed in the [relevant Meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294103/burninate-management-studio).

Comment: Ok! Thanks for clarifying the actual situation, this gives me a much better insight into what happened here. And thanks for rolling back my rollback - the edit makes more sense considering the clarified circumstances.