# Confused with the definitions of canvas and html5-canvas

Tags: discussion, tags

I had an [edit rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8896101) because of these two tags, and I remember of checking their definitions and pondering on what make of them.

I ended up leaving the two together, as I thought the question would be found easier in canvas related searches.

Still, it got re-edited, just to fix that.

I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253790/1579771), of course, just to prove me wrong - but then, **isn't their definitions a bit shady?**

**canvas**:
*"Canvas is a drawing element introduced to web development with HTML5."*

**html5-canvas:**
*"Canvas is an HTML element that allows for dynamic, scriptable rendering of 2D shapes, and bitmap images."*

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294126/why-can-you-suggest-an-edit-that-just-changes-a-tag-to-one-of-its-synonyms) - looking for tagging clues, and checked [this area](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) too.

Still a bit lost - help?

Comment: Is this a [meta-tag:synonym-request]? a [meta-tag:burninate-request]?

Comment: Are you asking about the rejected edit or are you more concerned with the tags being too similar?

Comment: @apaul34208 Neither - a discussion request. The fact that they are too similar (to my eyes, at least), led me to my mistake.

Comment: But you are discussing about [tags]

Comment: What I don't understand is why @KenY-N even rejected you when he has 2k already. Could have approved it then just added the last tag himself without trouble.. I see this happen all the time and it doesn't make sense for them to reject lower rep edits and then do almost the exact same thing.

Comment: @CayceK Yeah, as pointed by Paul in his answer, Braiam is retagging canvas questions, and just wanted to get the job done - as he was going to edit it anyway, it didn't matter if it was accepted or rejected. The way the "_approve_", "_reject_", "_improve edit_", and "_reject and edit_" system works might be a question for another post.

Comment: @Braiam Oh, a meta tag tag! Guess I missed that as well - thank you.

Comment: Just my two cents but what makes it even more confusing IMO is that most questions about the html [canvas] or [html5-canvas] are about the [CanvasRenderingContext2D API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) and not about the `<canvas>` element. People able to help about this API are not necessarly the same as those who can help for [WebGL] which is also drawn in the canvas element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There wasn't anything wrong with the retag, [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) and [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas)  [should be synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253790/html5-canvas-tag-should-be-a-synonym-of-the-canvas-tag).

---

Hmmm...

It looks like you may have been swept up in the retagging effort.

[The user who rejected your edit commented on the synonym request earlier.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253790/html5-canvas-tag-should-be-a-synonym-of-the-canvas-tag#comment224407_253790)

Comment: I don't think so - It was the third revision; Jordan had already cleaned that up. Unless you tell me my edit would revert Jordan's; but when I open my review here, it doesn't show as such.

Comment: @DanielGomes sorry about that, long day...

Comment: Welll... concluding from that question that they should be synonyms is a bit shaky. That something should be done though, indubitable.