# Willl someone please synonymize [uitableviewcelll] with [uitableviewcell]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Thee tagg [uitableviewcelll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcelll) hass ann incorrectlyy repeatedd letterr att thee endd.

The class the tag describes is `UITableViewCell`: note the presence of only two terminal 'l's. Presumably it was created because of the synonymificationizing of [uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcell) into [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview).

Regardless of the reason, a deliberately misspelled tag is, welll, dumb. Could it be merged or synonymerated, or whatever, into its correctly-spelled relation please?

Comment: Is 128 questions to much for a manual retag?

Comment: I suppose not, but [that appears to be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcelll) moot.

Comment: Related [Do we really need a tag synonym to cover a typo?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289653)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because [uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcell) was a synonym of [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview), I've pointed [uitableviewcelll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcelll) in the same direction and made it a synonym of the same.

Comment: Does that mean you're not in favour of burninating?