# Undo [uitableviewcell] -> [uitableview] tag synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I do not believe [uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcell) and [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview) should be synonyms.

1. A similar reusable view class in the iOS SDK [uicollectionview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uicollectionview) and its counterpart [uicollectionviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uicollectionviewcell) are not synonyms of each other.
2. On the Android side, [tablerow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablerow) and [tablelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablelayout) (and related tags) are not synonyms.
3. There may be questions about [methods and properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/) on `UITableViewCell` objects that do not apply to their parent `UITableView`.  An example of this might be how to add an accessory to a `UITableView` cell, which can be answered without knowing the details of its parent `UITableView`.

There are over 44,000 questions tagged with [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview) with over 35,000 being questions about cell behavior specifically: cell sizes, initializers, and memory management.  Adding an additional tag for [uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcell) objects will make finding questions specific to cell behavior easier.

On a related note: the [uitableviewcelll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcelll) tag should renamed [uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcell) to correct its typo.

Comment: You can't ask a question about `UITableViewCell` that doesn't relate to `UITableView`. I don't think it is good practice to tag questions by class name.

Comment: @BryanChen how about adding an [accessory view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW43) to a cell?  That doesn't require any knowledge of the table view itself, only the cell.

Comment: Your "related note" [was already handled](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319605/willl-someone-please-synonymize-uitableviewcelll-with-uitableviewcell), although it will have to be re-handled if the rest of your proposal takes effect.

Comment: I think it's amazing that such a logical suggestion falls of deaf ears. It makes no sense to so many tags under this [uitableview], but, AFAIK, for no other equivalent hierarchy throughout Stack Overflow.