# Tag length limit may be limiting technology discoverability

Tags: discussion, tags

I was editing [a question's tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887775/reload-only-one-section-header-in-uitableview/44888195#44888195) this morning and ran into the tag length limit:

[image: screenshot of the "tag too long" warning]

I understand the rationale for this to be that there needs to be *some* reasonable length of tag names, but this example has me questioning if 25 is the right length. Here's why:

1. Tags have the following properties:

   - They are searchable on Stack Overflow.
   - Because tags are searchable, they associate questions with similar questions.
   - Can lead users to find the right answers. For example, if a similar question has a tag pointing to a technology that an OP wasn't aware of.
2. Objective-C [traditionally has verbose class names](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) and even more verbose method signatures.
3. Class names seem to be valid tags. ([This meta request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319613/undo-uitableviewcell-uitableview-tag-synonym) makes a similar assumption.)

In this particular case, I wanted to add the tag to the question so that the OP and other users know to use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instead of `UITableViewCell` inside the framework method that the OP asked about. I can tag the question `UITableViewCell`, but that was the exact mistake the user was making, expressed as a tag. (Using one class instead of the other.)

I said as much in the answer, but the absence of the tag is obscuring the existence of the technology in some way and a missed opportunity for tags.

As such, we probably want to allow users to be able to tag questions with the "technologies" being used. This begs the question: how granular should tags be?

Given this understanding of tags, should we have a longer maximum tag length? Should tags be less specific if the class name is longer than the max length?

Comment: Hey can I get some feedback on this question, please? (Beyond downvotes. :D)

Comment: Why would you add a tag to tell people to use one technology or another? Isn't that what answers should be used for? IMO, we have too many tags as it is. Having a tag for every possible class name seems exorbitant.

Comment: Answers are indeed for telling people to use a particular class, but they also signal several things to OPs, drive-by-readers, and potential answer-ers. They offer context beyond the question.

Comment: Tags are not to give context, they are to classify questions. This... is just too fine grained of classification, to the point of not being useful as a classification.

Comment: It's possible to learn from classification, and I think that in the Apple world, lots of useful tags are going to be too long. (In this case, there are other useful questions specific to this class.)

Comment: I am not an iOS guy, so I may be wrong.. but do we NEED the "UITableViewHeaderFooterView"? is it truly THAT different from "UITableView"? If you're an expert in "UITableView", aren't you an expert in the HeaderFooterView one as well?

Comment: Other than the names of classes/protocols/etc, which I agree with others would be too fine-grained, what other examples of Apple (or any) tags are there that would exceed the 25 char limit?

Comment: @Clive That's fair, but I guess we have a fundamental disagreement (and it looks like I'm in the minority) about tags being useful beyond classification.

Comment: Yeah I hadn't looked beyond the "accepted" definition really, in my experience tags tend to become less meaningful/useful when people use them for anything beyond classification. Maybe I'm just being narrow-minded. If there were examples beyond one vendor though, it might help to make a more persuasive case. But then I guess it's not going to be hard to find long class names in a lot of languages/frameworks, so maybe it is more of a fundamental thing

Comment: Added this link to the post, inline: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html

Comment: @Moshe you might also want to look at some of the retag-request/syn requests regarding related tags: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Uitableview

Comment: (total OT) it's kinda funny that the question about '25 character limit' has exactly -25 vote rating

Answer (score 8):

There is a practical limit to how specific tags ought to be.

The principal purpose of tags is to make it easier for answerers to find questions to answer. I'm not an Objective-C user, but if I were looking to answer questions about Objective-C APIs, I'd probably look in the Objective-C tag, or the iOS tag or whatever. I would not be looking for questions about every class in Objective-C's API.

> In this particular case, I wanted to add the tag to the question so that the OP and other users know to use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instead of `UITableViewCell` inside the framework method that the OP asked about.

Even if we ignore the above, this is still wrong. Tags are for the *question*, not the *answers*. You don't tag questions based on how you solve the problem; you tag questions based on what the problem actually is.

That is how we let people know what technology to use. You see someone ask about X, and you read the answer showing how to use Y to do that job.