# Synonym proposal: [uilongpressgesturerecogni] -> [uilongpressgesturerecognizer]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

There was apparently a time when tags were limited to 25 characters, but that limit appears to have been lifted.

[Tag length limit may be limiting technology discoverability](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351625/tag-length-limit-may-be-limiting-technology-discoverability) exhibits the old limit, but e.g. [the Stack Overflow Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query help sidebar reveals that this is now

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| `TagName` | `nvarchar (35)` |

Browsing this tag reveals that this is apparently an IOS gesture; there are related tags [uitapgesturerecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitapgesturerecognizer) (which has a tag description with some documentation and links) and the base class (?) [uigesturerecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uigesturerecognizer)

It is unclear to me whether these individual subclass tags are really necessary; perhaps they should all be merged as synonyms with the superclass?

In fact, [the `uigesturerecognizer` tag's synonyms tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/uigesturerecognizer/synonyms) already contains synonym proposals for the following to be merged as synonyms of that tag:

- [uipangesturerecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uipangesturerecognizer)
- [uipinchgesturerecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uipinchgesturerecognizer)
- [uitapgesturerecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitapgesturerecognizer)

I would suppose these should also be nominated:

- [uiswipegesturerecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiswipegesturerecognizer)
- [uilongpressgesturerecogni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uilongpressgesturerecogni) with the new proposed synonym [uilongpressgesturerecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uilongpressgesturerecognizer)

I don't have enough rep in these tags to do anything about it, but someone who is familiar with the topic will probably have the required 5 rep to propose the synonym(s).

Comment: Props to @oguzismail for uncovering this.

Comment: ... and to @rene for explaining the tag length limits.

Comment: Yeah, I think *they should all be merged as synonyms with the superclass*.

Comment: Just *one* more tag: `containerfortagsthathaveanametoolon`

Comment: Can't we get rid of such ridiculous tags altogether?

Comment: @usr1234567 The synonyms are one concrete way to accomplish that. Removing a tag only gets rid of it until somebody gets the bright idea to recreate it because it seems to be missing. A synonym fixes that (for some value of "fix" and "that") by redirecting to the canonical tag and preventing tag revival.

Comment: @usr1234567 Can you explain what makes these tags "ridiculous"? It is useful to have tags that relate to key technology used in the question, including individual classes/components.

Comment: @tripleee or  we just say that function/class tags makes no sense and apply that  generally. That way it "doesn't look" like it's missing  because there's no tags about a single function/class.  :)

Comment: Truly we live in the future when tags can be more than 25 characters long.

Comment: @Braiam The flaw with that is that Eternal September has an unlimited supply of new users who have no idea what our lofty principles are.

Comment: Luckily for us, they can't create tags on a whim. But we have to teach them yesterday about that. :)

Comment: @CodyGray They are difficult to read and are super specific. pangesture, pinchgesture - ok. Not these monsters. You are not talking about Java classes, but tags.

Comment: Other tags with the same problem include `mediabrowserservicecompat`, `continuation-local-storag`, `constrained-execution-reg`, `azure-app-service-envrmnt`, `pfquerytableviewcontrolle`, `ckfetchrecordchangesopera`, `gml-geographic-markup-lan`, `uiprintinteractioncntrler`, `gradle-android-test-plugi`, `sql-server-migration-assi`, `uimodalpresentationformsh`, `multiple-interface-implem`, `unauthorizedaccessexcepti`, `validation-application-bl`, `stringbyevaluatingjavascr` and `visual-studio-setup-proje`. There are probably plenty more that are missing some punctuation.

Comment: The name of the 25-character tag appears to make no sense (apart from existing because of the arbitrary 25-character limit). So I don't see a reason to believe anyone would ever try to recreate it. Simply renaming or merging the tag makes more sense than adding a synonym.

Comment: Sure, the discussion in the comments is about getting rid of these other tags, which _are_ somewhat likely to reappear if they are not made into synonyms.

Comment: Thanks for the list; I started working on a separate post about those, but ran out of steam.

Comment: @tripleee Are you advocating new tags that use as many characters as needed without being the previously-truncated versions (meh), replacing those tags with the untruncated versions (ok), or are you asking for all the `ui*gesturerecognizer` tags to be collapsed to `uigesturerecognizer` (yay!)?

Comment: Ironic that the tag name has "long" in it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm not entirely sure; that's why this is [tag:discussion] - but like you, I'm gravitating towards the "yay" option. I think a separate post for other truncated tags to implement the "ok" optoion more broadly would be in order but it's work in progress.

Comment: @CodyGray There is nothing these tags accomplish that can't be better accomplished just by including the class name in the question title. Not all terms related to a question need to be tags.

Answer (score 6):

Individual classes should not have dedicated tags. Full stop. Such tags make finding information *more* difficult by fragmenting it and drastically increasing the number of tags to consider. It furthermore makes it more difficult for developers with the relevant expertise to find the question (since they'll have to follow gobs and gobs of tags to be shown the question); in practice, this means that questions using such tags will attract less attention from those most able to answer them. A question about such a class may not even use the class in the best answer; another approach using a different portion of the API may be better. As such, it is *far* better for tags to be more general. If someone is looking for information about a specific class, that need only be a search *term*, not a tag in their search.

These should be merged into whatever overarching API they're part of.

Comment: So is this a vote in favor of making all the individual tags into synonyms of [tag:uigesturerecognizer]? Or do you want to take it even further?

Comment: @tripleee I believe the last sentence of my answer makes the course of action I'm suggesting clear.

Comment: No, it's not; that's why I'm requesting a clarification. Do you mean to say there is an "overarching API" which they all should be merged into?

Comment: @tripleee I don't know what API this class comes from. Is it in a library? Part of the language's standard lib? Part of a well known module or namespace within the standard lib or a large library? Whatever it's a part of, it can be tagged with that. Obviously, if individual classes are too fine grained a level for tags, then whatever higher level grouping the class belongs to is the tag to use.

Comment: @tripleee I would guess that the [tag:uikit] framework would be appropriate for this specific set of examples: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer. A framework is an appropriate level of expertise for a tag. Some frameworks are large enough to justify tags for specific parts of them, but definitely not down to individual classes.