# Retag [uitableviewcelll] as [uitableview]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Can we please retag [uitableviewcelll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcelll) questions as [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview)?

It looks like it's already been defined as a synonym ([Willl someone please synonymize [uitableviewcelll] with [uitableviewcell]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319605/1271826)), but it would appear that there are old questions linked to the old tag, because when tagging a question, [uitableviewcelll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcelll) continues to be shown prominently (presumably because there are still questions linked to it), whereas the other [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview) synonyms just show up listed under "also" under their main tag:

[image]

Personally, I think tag synonyms are silly for these rare typos (i.e.  when done retagging, I'd suggest deleting [uitableviewcelll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcelll) tag/synonym altogether), but perhaps that's a separate topic (e.g. [Do we really need a tag synonym to cover a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289653/do-we-really-need-a-tag-synonym-to-cover-a-typo)).

Comment: Wouldn't this problem be non-existent if [tag:uitableviewcelll] was [merged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131528/167646) into [tag:uitableviewcell] instead of being made a synonym of [tag:uitableview]?

Comment: Personally, I disagree. See [Undo \[uitableviewcell\] -> \[uitableview\] tag synonym](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319613/2415822)

Comment: @JAL - I agree with you re [uitableviewcell] -> [uitableview] and the fairly arbitrary nature of why it was done for that class hierarchy, but not myriad other hierarchies (e.g. why for table views, but not collection views). IMHO, arbitrary decisions like [uitableviewcell] -> [uitableview] quickly become entrenched orthodoxy and and are defended vigorously. But my concern here was to the existence of [uitableviewcelll] as suggestion when tagging questions. And rather than debating whether it is a synonym of [uitableview] or [uitableviewcell], once it's merged, we should just delete it.

Comment: That's fair as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I forgot these hang around as suggestions when I created the synonym, so I've merged [uitableviewcelll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcelll) into [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview).

That should remove the former and take care of this.