# Should we forget about [memorization]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-synonym-process

There are [9 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memorization) with the [memorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memorization) tag; isn't this just a misspelling of [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memoization)?

Most questions seem to be about memoization, sometimes even using the correct spelling in the title. [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020782/find-closest-memorable-word-to-better-learn-cs-jargon) [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159967/good-mnemonic-for-when-to-use-the-word-table) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180971/memorizing-important-algorithms-such-as-binary-search) about how to memorize programming terms and concepts, but I assume these are off-topic for SO anyway, or should at least use a less confusing term like "mnemonics".

I edited the tag on a question today, only to have the changes reverted, so apparently there are people who are convinced that it is the correct spelling. Maybe synonymization would be better that burninization, to avoid it being recreated?

Comment: Isn't the correct spelling "memoi**s**ation"?

Comment: I wouldn't synonymise misspellings; rather edit it out of the places it doesn't belong and perchance make [memorization] a synonym of [memory].

Comment: @Olaf Most people think British spelling should use -ise instead of -ize, but that is a popular misconception. Most words can be spelled with both -ise and -ize, but there are a few exceptions, like excise, where -cise is from the latin for cutting, so people use -ise to be safe.

Comment: @m69: ESL, but I know British people who insist using the `s` instead of `z` for most `ise` forms (maybe I should ask them if there are exceptions). From the origin as stated in Wikipedia, I'd actually assume the `s` form would be the original spelling actually. But if you insist on the `z`, it's not worth my time to discuss.

Comment: Casn you provide a link to the particular question? These are two different things and maybe there should be two different tags. I agree, thought the wikis should point out there is a difference in the brief.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure [memorization] as in "how to remember programming terms or concepts" should even be a tag, as those questions seem very much off-topic to me. And having both tags will just lead to the one being misused for the other;

Comment: @m69: I had to think about it myself about the differences, but without much thinking, there maybe there are usages for AI algorithms and machine learning, etc? Anyway, looks like there are quite some off-topic questions for [tag:memorization] at least.

Comment: @Olaf Well, there are only 22, so it's easy to get a quick overview of what's there.

Comment: Feel free to request burnination if you think it is irrelevant. (yes, I saw the tag, but the title could be a bit more clear, I think.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks. Will you add a warning to the tag wiki not to use the [memorization] tag for memoization questions, or are you going to have the tag synonymized or burninated anyway?

Comment: The tag is burninated, @m69

Answer (score 25):

Well, "memorization" is not a valid tag for Stack Overflow. And it is an English word (and therefore allowed by spell-checkers) that is a single letter away from something that *is* a valid tag. Given this fact, it is highly likely that, even if we retag the existing questions, users will continue to make this spelling mistake in the future. So the tag is pretty much guaranteed to return.

So I'm in favor of full-on blacklisting for the tag.

Comment: Not to mention autocorrect.

Comment: If most uses of [memorization] are simply [memoization] incorrectly corrected and not users carelessly misspelling it, I think it would be more user-friendly to just make it a synonym. On the other hand, it does mean deliberate uses of [memorization] get incorrectly (and silently) rewritten to [memoization]...

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't think we *want* deliberate use of [memorization]; it's not tag-worthy. As for the synonym idea, is there precedent for using synonyms for mis-spellings?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Yes - though I'm not sure if there is for using misspellings that are themselves valid, unrelated words, as in this case.

Comment: I think that auto-complete will reduce the rate of future misspellings.

Comment: slightly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289653/do-we-really-need-a-tag-synonym-to-cover-a-typo

Answer (score 3):

9 questions isn't really enough to justify a site-wide effort to eliminate it. You can individually retag the memoization questions and remove the tag from the remainder yourself in less than an hour.

*Isn't autocorrect **fun**?*

Comment: That will most likely have the tag re-added by someone sooner or later. I'm also not sure the tag has it's applications.

Answer (score -2):

What about changing the memoRization tag description to be something like:

> Not to be confused with memoization (technique used to speed up algorithms by storing the results of function calls)

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this will get people to notice the misspelling. Also, since memoRization is not tag-worthy, it's not clear what the *rest* of the usage information would be.