# Should we forget [mnemonics]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There is no usage guidance/tag wiki for [mnemonics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mnemonics).  Its conventional [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mnemonics) is not programming related:

> a technique of improving the memory

It has 5 followers and very low activity (one question in the past 2 years).

There are currently [115 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mnemonics) tagged with [mnemonics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mnemonics).  I am not finding a single common programming-related theme.  Some repeated topics in rough descending order of frequency include:

- Keyboard shortcuts in menus (See Forms and Menu buttons below)
- Assembly language / opcodes
- Generating a list or phrase for use as a password/private key
- Remembering how various variable/function/method names/slash-types/regexps differ

I did find a few on-topic questions including:

- Swing/JavaFX menu buttons (JButton/JMenu setMnemonic method), the most common ones
- Windows Forms (Label.UseMnemonic property)
- Generating a random list of words for cryptocurrency (Bitcoin BIP39)
- Mnemonics settings in IntelliJ IDE

Looking at the [criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/7508700) for burnination:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It does not do so for on-topic questions, which are associated with specific methods, properties, algorithms, or IDE options, where it simply repeats the name of something mentioned in the question.

It does describe the contents of several off-topic questions like "How do I remember ...?"

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Only in the context of the usage of keyboard shortcuts in menu/form APIs, but seems to be more of a meta tag.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No.  The tags [keyboard-shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcut), [keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keypress), or [keyevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyevent) describe questions related to user behavior, while the tags [jmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmenu), [menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menubar), [jlabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jlabel) and [jbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbutton) seem better suited to specific, on-topic UI questions.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. The diversity of question types the list above shows meanings from keyboard shortcuts to programmer memory aids to algorithms.

**Additonal thoughts**

The tag doesn't seem to be used for mnemonics-related questions anyway. Compare the 115 questions with 3045 posts [containing the word "mnemonic"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mnemonic).

There was a [previous burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359018/should-we-forget-about-memorization) of the [memorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memorization) tag. While it seemed a misspelling of "memoization", and comments suggested [mnemonics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mnemonics) as an alternative, the top-voted answer stated:

> Well, "memorization" is not a valid tag for Stack Overflow.

My only hesitation is the question of "active harm". It's hard to say it's attracting off-topic questions when it's rarely being used.  However, in the one recent case I do think it was used in place of a probably better tag.

Comment: I agree with this use (wikipedia):
a mnemonic is a symbolic name for a single executable machine language instruction (an opcode), and there is at least one opcode mnemonic defined for each machine language instruction.

Comment: Upvoted because it's ages since I've seen a punny title!

Comment: As both the JavaFX and the Windows Forms related questions show, mnemonic is also often used to refer to the key associated with an action that can be used in combination with Alt to invoke it. Not exactly a shortcut, but not far off either.

Comment: That tag is history.

Comment: FWIW, the official name in Win32 for "the thing that appears underlined to indicate what you should press in combination with Alt to get it" is "keyboard accelerator", which is a term adopted by many other UI frameworks as well. "Shortcut" is common in popular parlance as well but has its own list of overloaded meanings, of course.

Comment: While i agree with @Stefan, I think that mnemonics of this kind can all be covered with the "assembler" tag, right?

Comment: @clockw0rk: Yes, there's no need for a specific tag for questions about instruction mnemonics, `[assembly]` + a tag like `[mips]` for whatever ISA is fine.  Maybe also `[instructions]`, although that tag is kind of useless and arbitrary for most purposes.  You definitely wouldn't want to filter on `[instructions]` or `[mnemonics]` if you were searching for an answer to something; no guarantee that an existing question would frame it in those terms, or use those tags even if they did come at the problem from the same angle you are.

Comment: @PeterCordes Wouldn't [tag:opcode] be a less ambiguous tag to use for these? There's also [tag:instruction-set] and [tag:isa].

Comment: @Lundin: There are a bunch of nebulous tags without any clear distinction.  ISA and instruction-set should probably be synonyms. However, opcodes are a machine-code concept, mnemonics are a text assembly-language concept; there is a clear distinction there.  e.g. on x86, `jge` (greater or equal) and jnl` (not less) are synonyms: two different mnemonics for the same opcode.  Also on x86, `04` is the opcode for a 2-byte instruction `add al, imm8`.  There are many other encodings of [`add`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add), with 10 different opcodes for the same mnemonic.

Answer (score 5):

As you said, it probably doesn't matter much. But the fact that it has been used in the past without much benefit, as you seem to indicate, tells me that we'd be better off deleting it to avoid it being a substitute for better tags.

While I cannot say that I have looked at all uses of the tag, I have experience with mnemonics in the context of human memory and I am familiar with assembler, which makes me comfortable enough to say that it's not a specific enough tag to keep around. My vote: remove it.