# Can we boot [boostrap-grid] and boost [bootstrap-grid]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[boostrap-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boostrap-grid) is clearly misspelt (*boo*strap-grid instead of *boot*strap-grid). Maybe it should be [twitter-bootstrap-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-grid) to bring it in line with the other Bootstrap tags. It also doesn't have a wiki. Would someone like to clean it up please?

Comment: There are 65 questions in the misspelt tag. And [tag:bootstrap-grid] exists

Comment: Only 45 questions for [tag:bootstrap-grid]. Maybe they should be merged and renamed.

Comment: Oh god, [it begins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199811/boostrap-am-i-going-insane#comment635570_199811).

Comment: Woudln't the simplest solution be to synonymize them to the correct spelling?

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited?rq=1

Comment: I have submitted some tag info for [tag:bootstrap-grid]. Once that's done maybe we can find some folks to recommend synonymizing it, though I think an expedited re-tag/burnination effort would be quicker.

Comment: @MrLister ["bootstarp"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bootstarp)...

Comment: related: [Do we really need a tag synonym to cover a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289653/do-we-really-need-a-tag-synonym-to-cover-a-typo)

Comment: [The typo could be worse](https://i.imgur.com/wTf7QOc.png?1)

Comment: @Tanner We'd agree that a merge would be better, but that can only be done by a mod, so we should first make it a synonym.

Answer (score 8):

Call me crazy, but I've retagged all of the questions with the misspelt tag to use [bootstrap-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-grid). Hopefully no more pop up because there was a lot. I'd suggested blocking the misspelt version from being added again otherwise this will keep happening. Whether or not I can do that I'm not sure, but I tried to help.

Comment: Hmm, I'm seeing five questions still tagged in the count, but no questions actually listed. Cache?

Comment: Ah okay, I had some ignored tags being hidden. All should be retagged now.